# Two way address translation or what?

Tags: c++, assembly, arm

I am looking at the ARM assembly code for a C++ native code. Target platform is Windows Phone 8, and build environment is Visual Studio 2012.

I am inspecting the ARM assembly code to look for possibilities of code optimisation to the maximum.

I am confused regarding the requirement for one of the instruction in the ARM code, as under.

**C++ Code:**

```
double lmean= kseedsl[n];
```

**ARM Code:**

```
1: ldr r3,[sp,#0x4C]
2: ldr r3,[r3]                     // r3= kseedsl
3: add r2,r3,r6,lsl #3             // r2 = &kseedsl[n] (r6 has value of "n")
4: vldr d13,[r2]                   // d13 = *(r2)
```

I understand that the addresses for variables such as `kseedsl`(which is an input arguement in the function) is stored in the stack. But I am clueless why we require two `ldr` (line1, 2) to load the address of `kseedsl` into r3. As per my knowledge, I would have expected `[sp,#0x4C]` to directly store the address for kseedsl which is passed as a function arguement.

Kindly point out what I am missing over here.
I expect it to be a standard concept which I am unaware of.

**EDIT:** The skeleton of the function is as under:

```
void function_xyz(
    vector<double>&             kseedsl,
    vector<double>&             kseedsa,
    vector<double>&             kseedsb,
    vector<int>&                kseedsx,
    vector<int>&                kseedsy,
    unsigned short*             klabels,
    const int&                  STEP,
    const double&               M,
    int                         Iter,
    int                         *oMaxSegsize);
```

Comment: How many arguments does your function have?  In normal ARM ABIs, the first few arguments are passed in registers.  Can you show some more context?

Comment: I have edited the question as per your query. Kindly refer to that. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `kseedsl` is a `std::vector<double>&`, you need two load instructions to get at the actual data contained in the vector.

The first load instruction loads the location of the `std::vector` object itself into r3.
The second load instruction loads the address of the data area managed by the `std::vector`. This happens to be stored in the first member of the `std::vector` in your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated*
`kseedsl` is passed as a reference to the object on the stack since its type is `vector<>&`.  The first `ldr` gets the object's reference from the stack—the address of where the object actually is stored.  The second `ldr` dereferences (uses it as indirection) the reference to obtain the address of the vector.  From there it is straightforward indexing.

Comment: Well. I am confused here. I would expect the first ldr to give *(sp+0x4C), i.e. the value should already be dereferenced because of ldr, isn't it? So that r3 should be storing the address of kseedsl after the first ldr itself?

Comment: @vishal:  I had not noticed the declaration of `kseedsl` before.  I have updated my answer.